# A word or short phrase to reduce the influence of something

Tags: antonyms, semantics

When talking about depression, I prefer to use positive/active words as opposed to combative or oppressive words. I'm looking for a word that fits in this sentence that is active and positive:

> I can use this technique (to?) ________ depression

I thought about something like *disempower*, but to me it feels more oppressive, like taking power away. I'm looking for a word that reduces the implied power in the first place, like dimming a light vs shading it. Possibly like you see in films, where the imaginary influence becomes smaller and less significant, vs binding it.

Comment: You could use. Combat?

Comment: I specifically don't want to use combative words. Combat still gives power to the opponent. It becomes an endless arms race that can never end.

Comment: How about "alleviate"?

Comment: @Eris: Don't overthink things. It's perfectly normal to talk about therapies that [combat depression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+alleviate+depression%2Cto+combat+depression&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20alleviate%20depression%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20combat%20depression%3B%2Cc0), and no normal person would think that was a "combative" usage, or see any connection to ideas like "Combat still gives power to the opponent".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not "normal", I have depression. As I discover more ways to assuage it, I find it works a lot better when there isn't a fight to "win".

Comment: [*reduce, diminish, decrease, lessen, assuage, alleviate, ease, relieve, soothe, soften, take the edge off, dull, cushion, mollify, moderate, calm, lull, temper, mitigate, palliate, blunt, deaden, abate, tone down*](http://www.seadict.com/en/en/allay)

Comment: In addition to *mollify* and *mitigate*, you might also consider *attenuate* and *pacify*.

Comment: "to *counter* depression".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the word 'ameliorate' in this usage. While not well known, which may require some explanation, it's meaning is so much more about redirecting that combating something - it literally means to take a bad thing and make it better.

It also has a soft, soothing sound to it...

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> I can use this technique to [alleviate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alleviate) depression.

Comment: Not quite, but you did lead me to the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Hugh-Meyers, I found the word I was looking for:

> [**assuage**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assuage) *əˈswāj*
>
> *verb*: make (an unpleasant feeling) less intense.
>
> "the letter assuaged the fears of most members"

Answer (score 1):

Mitigate.

> 1. to lessen in force or intensity, as wrath, grief, harshness, or pain; moderate.
> 2. to make less severe: to mitigate a punishment.
> 3. to make (a person, one's state of mind, disposition, etc.) milder or more gentle; mollify; appease.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mitigate)

Answer (score 0):

**Counter**, as in **off-set**. Although counter itself can be opposing!

Definition of counter (Entry 3 of 7) transitive verb. 1a : to act in opposition to : oppose. b : offset, nullify tried to counter the trend toward depersonalization. 2 : to assert in answer We countered that our warnings had been ignored.

Source - Google
People also ask:**What is the definition of counter?**
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+counter

Comment: Whose definition are you using?

Comment: Google, See edit, I thought of the word 'counter' before checking as it, does sound a little negative but, seemed to flow nicely.